# Why Vsphere host ends with /sdk?

Tags: vsphere, metricbeat

Why do I need to include the **/sdk** to the end of my host adress? For exampple, if I set my host to **https://vcenter.test.ca** I get a server error but with **https://vcenter.test.ca/sdk** it runs fine.

The content of my metricbeat.yml looks like this:

```
metricbeat.modules:
        # Vsphere module
      - module: vsphere
        enabled: true
        metricsets: ["datastore", "host", "virtualmachine"]
        period: 60s
        **hosts: ["https://vcenter.test.ca/sdk"]**
        username: "test@test.ca"
        password: "****"
        insecure: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the the **/sdk** at the end of the url is the API route. If it is not inlcuded in your url you will get:

```
"error": {
  "message": "Post https://vcenter.test.ca: **x509: certificate signed by unknown authority**"
},
```